# Check if a type DIRECTLY derives from (is a child of) another type in an "enable if" context

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfinae, enable-if, subtype

C++ has [`is_base_of<Base,Derived>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of). However, this also includes “grandparent” types.

Is there a way to get have `is_child_of<Parent,Child>` functionality? The purpose is to use types as *sentinel 'interface' markers* in an SFINAE context, without being affected by sentinels that may or may not be added to parent types.

That is, the following output is expected to be "true, false". (The output with `is_base_of` is "true, true".)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};

class B : A {};

class C : B {};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "a2b: " << std::is_child_of<A, B>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "a2c: " << std::is_child_of<A, C>::value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I see nothing in the traits library, like this. You're almost asking about reflection, which, as we know, C++ doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have reflection, child's storage contain's parent's storage and it's hard to draw a line between one subobject and another. Some metaprogramming must be dome, mimicking libraries similar to Qt or MFC\WFC

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> 

#define DECLARE_CLASS(Name,  ParentName)  using Parent = ParentName;
#define PARENT_CLASS(Name) Name::Parent

class LibBase {
public:
     DECLARE_CLASS(LibBase,  void)
};

class A : public LibBase {
public:
    DECLARE_CLASS(A,  LibBase)
};

class B : public A {
public:
    DECLARE_CLASS(B,  A)
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_same<PARENT_CLASS(B), A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<PARENT_CLASS(B), LibBase>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Clearly this simple approach have pitfall that we don't get an error if class is not defined using our macro., and it is static only,

First issue can  worked around by creating a "trait" nested class by declaration, which got name based on class name passed to DECLARE_OBJECT.  This would make result of PARENT_CLASS(Name) unique, e.g.

```
#define DECLARE_CLASS(Name,  ParentName)  struct TraitsOf##Name { \
    using Parent = ParentName; \
};

#define PARENT_CLASS(Name) Name::TraitsOf##Name::Parent
```

Second issue can be worked around by  creating own RTTI function within macro-definition

Sadly form `is_child_of<LibBase, A>::value` is unattainable with this because macro substitution happens before template substitution. Perhaps some static registering approach can be used to give classes unique traits in wait how BOOST_TYPEOF does but getting rid of macrodefinitions in user code would be nigh-impossible.